# Stopping process flow in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a SAS program as follows, which tries to check if a certain file exists.

```
%let testfile = \\some.network.share\SOMEFILE.CSV;

%macro findit;
  %if %sysfunc(fileexist(&testfile)) %then %do;
    %put The file exists! ;
  %end;
  %else %put The file does not exist! ;
%mend;

%findit;
```

I want to change the program as follows: if that file is not found, the rest of the SAS program, and the following programs in the Process Flow should be ignored and the analysis should end right there.

Is that possible?

Comment: Does the network node exist?  I tried running your exact example and SAS was hanging because Windows was waiting on a response from a computer named `some.network.share`.  If I remove the \\ or use a real computer name then it works.

Comment: How are you submitting the code? Are you using Enterprise Guide? SAS display manager? Running a saved SAS file from the command line? Stored process server? ....

Comment: Your path name shouldn't have quotes. Try it without that. See the example in the documentation which is similar to what you're trying to do. http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/69726/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n108rtvqj4uf7tn13tact6ggb6uf.htm

Comment: Excellent comments. I am using SAS EG. That network share does exist (when I open it in File Explorer, it works and shows the file). I will try without quotes shortly.

Comment: Alright, thanks to your comments, the issue with paths is solved now. Can we move to the actual question of stopping the process flow if the file is not found?

Answer (score 0):

Check out documentation for %goto and use like this:

```
%macro findit;
  %if %sysfunc(fileexist(&testfile)) %then %do;
    %put The file exists! ;
  %end;
  %else %do;
    %put The file does not exist! ;
    %goto exit; 
  %end;


%exit:
%mend;
```

Note that the destination %exit is followed by a colon, not a semi-colon.

Comment: This assumes that I can wrap the entire process flow into a macro, right? I am not sure if I can do that as the process flow involves very long programs themselves containing macros and whatnot, but I will give it a try and report back.